# ImageView to zoom out and scale the image animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation, splash-screen

I want image to zoom out and scale as Twitter Splash screen animation but I am not able to first zoom out the image and scale. Here's is my code

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.animate()
                    .setStartDelay(500)
                    .setDuration(1000)
                    .scaleX(20)
                    .scaleY(20)
                    .alpha(0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention scale from variable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" >
    </scale>
 </set>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost any animations with `ObjectAnimator` and it's very smooth.

Here is a sample code. In this case image will scale up from 1x to 2x, You can adjust the values as your need.Now if you want to scale down then change 2x to 0.5x which will scale down image to 50% of original image.

```
    ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "scaleX", 1.0f, 2.0f);
    scaleXAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    scaleXAnimation.setDuration(1500);
    ObjectAnimator scaleYAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "scaleY", 1.0f, 2.0f);
    scaleYAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    scaleYAnimation.setDuration(1500);
    ObjectAnimator alphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "alpha", 1.0F, 0F);
    alphaAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    alphaAnimation.setDuration(1500);


    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.play(scaleXAnimation).with(scaleYAnimation).with(alphaAnimation);
    animatorSet.setStartDelay(500);
    animatorSet.start();
```